# Correct choice of design pattern for different request types

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Having a very interesting problem here on design. Building an API which does scanning on the request that is being passed to scan API. Currently there are 2 types of request and they are totally different from one another. API has to support both of these requests. Also the design should work well if any new request is introduced in future.

Request 1:

```
class EmployeeReq {
      String name;
      String id;
      //getter,setter for the parameters.
      getName(); setName(name);
      getId(); setId(id);
}
```

Request 2:

```
class StudentReq {
      String studentName;
      String grade;
      //getter,setter for the parameters.
      getStudentName(); setStudentName(studentName);
      getGrade(); setGrade(grade);
}
```

API:
MyRequest: is either EmployeeReq or StudentReq, based on what client will send.

```
public MyResponse scan(MyRequest req) {
     //scan the request based on what parameters being passed as request.
     /**
     The scan engine should scan the req fields coming in.
     Which can be getName(); getId(); getStudentName(); getGrade();
     How can I achieve to access the different scan fields from different Request types at once place? 
     **/

}
```

Answer (score 1):

"program to interfaces, not implementations" is a good thing

Will this help?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

interface Request {
    String getType();
}

interface Response {
    // have method to return whatever response you want to return
}

interface RequestProcessor {
    Response process(Request request);
}

class StudentRequest implements Request {

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "student";
    }

}

class EmployeeRequest implements Request {

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "empoloyee";
    }

}

class StudentRequestProcessor implements RequestProcessor {
    // Process request
    @Override
    public Response process(Request request) {
        return null;
    }
}

final class Registry {
    // Singleton class
    private static Registry INSTANCE = new Registry();

    public static Registry getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private Map<String, RequestProcessor> processors = new HashMap<>();

    private Registry() {
        processors.put("student", new StudentRequestProcessor());
    }

    public RequestProcessor getRequestProcessor(Request request) {
        return processors.get(request.getType());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to know if the object is an instance of something, so try this:

```
if (obj instanceof Class) {
   // Your code.
}
```